# Recommended way to store temporary login information

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

In my scenario, I am trying to implement a login procedure to my example website by delegating the actual check to an external service via a 2-step operation, calling the same endpoint.

The first external step, with correct credentials, returns a temporary token which needs to be sent along with the second step credentials.
The seconds external step returns the actual token which is added to the user claims for my website.

The flow is as follows:

1. The user opens `mywebsite.com` and goes to login.
2. In the form enters the first tier of credentials and submits to `Account/Login`.
3. `AccountController.Login` calls `externalservice.com/login` and if it's returned a `step1_token` redirects the user to `Account/Login` where the next tier of credentials are requested.
4. The user enters them and again submits the form.
5. `AccountController.Login` again calls `externalservice.com/login` with the new credentials and the previous `step1_token`, if they are correct a `actual_token` is returned, the user is signed in and the `actual_token` is added to the user claims.
6. The user is redirected to a private area

I can't authenticate the user until the second step is completed, and I have no control over the external service
I'd like to reuse the same endpoint (`Account/Login`) for both steps but it's not necessary.

So far I tried:

- returning the token along with the response to the user, storing it in a hidden form field for the following request.
- storing the temporary token in the user session to retrieve it in the next request.

I am wondering if there is a better, safer or recommended way to do this.

Comment: You could store the token in a cookie or send in an HTTP header. Storing in a cookie also allows the possibility for users who authenticated recently to continue without logging in again, until the cookie expires or the user explicitly logs out.

Comment: Either of those solutions sound fine. "Safer" really depends on what you want to protect the token from. I'm guessing there's no problem if the user can see it, so as long as you're using HTTPS you should be fine. Alternatively, have the user type in both credentials at once and handle both steps purely back-end.

Comment: From your description, I think the steps are correct. Do think when you send token to `externalservice.com/login` is not safe?